# Ckeditor won't display text properly in asp.net mvc after exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor with ASP.NET MVC, I have this view (create view) which has a couple of input fields plus the ckedior, if an exception occurs in the controller's action method, the ckeditor displays raw html in it instead of the formated text.

For example, before submitting the form the editor displays the text like "This is a sample text" and after the error the editor displays `"<p><b>This is a sample text</b></p>"`

Here's how I'm using the ckeditor in the view

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ArticleDetails)
```

and the action method looks like something like that

```
public ActionResult Create(Article article)
{
  try
  {
   //some code
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  { 
   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Operation failed, " + ex.ToString());
  }

  return View(article);
}
```

And I have this set in the config file of ckeditor 
`config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;`

And this is how the ckeditor is initiated in the view

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="/Areas/Admin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            CKEDITOR.replace('ArticleDetails', {
                language: 'en'
            });
         });
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have something else than TextAreaFor to get a CKEditor instance... Is there something ou are not telling us? Anything in the developer console? Have you checked the generated HTML and JS? After all, CKE is just HTML and JS.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "Is there something you are not telling us?" Why would I intend to hide something that would help people help me in my problem!? In case you mean how do I initiate the ckeditor, I have edited the question and added the initiation.

Comment: There's nothing in the developer console, as for the generated HTML, after submitting the page the hidden text area contains the text in  this way &lt;p&gt;some text&lt;/p&gt

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to be facetious, but that is hard to do in text only communication. My bad, no offense intended! Can try bypassing `TextAreaFor` by manually creating a textarea? Just to test if that is  the problem. Then input the value for example similar to `<textarea ...>@Html.Raw(model.ArticleDetails)</textarea>`. Html.raw is sometimes very helpful when entities is the problem.

Comment: Doing so causes an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." because initially in the create view the model object is null so I added an if condition like this <textarea id="ArticleDetails">@if (Model != null) { Html.Raw(Model.ArticleDetails); }</textarea> but now when the form submits and the error occurs the editor is empty.